# Cannot use import statement outside a module Electron React Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, import, electron

How to solve the famous issue `"Cannot use import statement outside a module"` in an Electron-React-Typescript app?

```
//const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
```

Error :

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

in package.json I added :

```
"type": "module",
```

devDependencies in package.json :

```
"@types/node": "^14.14.28",
"@types/react": "^17.0.2",
"electron": "^11.2.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.5",
"webpack": "^5.21.2"
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/index.js",
    "dist",
  ]
}
```

I also added in babel.config.json 's plugins :

```
["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
  "allowTopLevelThis": true
}],
```

and in package.json :

```
"scripts": {
   "babel": "babel ./src/**/* -d dist",
   "start": "yarn run babel && electron .",
```

- electron : 11.2.3
- typescript : 4.1.5
- node: v14.5.0
- O.S. : Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop

What do I have to add / modify in order to be able to use "import" ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762278/typescript-react-electron-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module/65833235?noredirect=1#comment117059503_65833235

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to and Electron's expert I discovered two errors which caused that issue:

1. I modified the main's path in package.json

   `"main": "./src/main/main.ts"` ---> `"main": "./dist/main/main.js"`

   because electron can understand only the compiled file
2. I removed in package.js on

   `"type": "module"`

   which otherwise wuold require to change `.js  to` .cjs files

Comment: I don't have a main.js in my dist folder